# Example of C++ code in Visual Studio initializing a created raster

Tags: raster, gdal, visual-studio

I refer to [Sample for MS Visual Studio C++ using GDAL library](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150365/sample-for-ms-visual-studio-c-using-gdal-library)

I noticed that the answer mentions that when GDAL is built from source there would be a tools folder with examples of how to initialize a created raster. I have GDAL built from source (following the steps specified here: http://crowdsimulation.blogspot.com/2015/07/geospatial-data-abstraction-library.html?showComment=1452035822922#c1369732198978557869) in Visual Studio 2010 and a 32 bit machine.

However, I am not able to locate the tools folder with the examples. 
Is there any other source where I can obtain the examples? 
Can someone post a simple one?

Answer (score 2):

The GDAL website has a [tutorials section](https://gdal.org/tutorials/index.html). The [raster API tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) has examples for opening and creating GDAL raster datasets.